# How to periodically delete pod in Kubernetes cluster on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cron

I'd like to restart my service every day in the morning. When I do it manually I just remove the pod on GCP and it starts again. Alternatively I can use:

```
helm delete service_name-dev --purge
helm install service_name/ --namespace dev --name service_name-dev --values=service_name/google-dev-values.yaml
```

It would be easy to schedule it on my laptop, but is it possibile to schedule it on Google Cloud Platform so the service would be rebooted on the given time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `CronJob` object, set it to the schedule you need. Additionally, you need to create the necessary `ServiceAccount`, `Role` and `RoleBinding` resources for it, so it can delete the pods.

When you get those right, you can use the service account token that is mounted into your cronjob pod, to issue, for example, `kubectl delete pod -l <your-app-label>`. You could do it via kubectl, or through any Kubernetes client library in any language.

Please note that it is actually a bad practice to kill the application periodically, and most possibly an indicator to a problem in the application's design.

Comment: So is is necessary to create a separate pod with kubectl configured? I thought maybe GCP enables to automatically delete the pod. I know it's bad practice, but it's temporary solution.

Comment: Not a pod - you never create pods in Kubernetes. Rather, you create higher level resources such as `Deployment`, `StatefulSet` or in this case `CronJob` that creates/deletes pods as necessary - they manage the pod lifecycle. Here, when you create a CronJob, it will not create a pod immediately. It will only create pod according to the schedule you define - a pod that is short-lived (does one task and terminates). And that short lived pod will have `kubectl` inside (you can use this for example: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kubectl/), and its `command` will be `kubectl delete pod -l ..`